# Adding widget results in "AttributeError: 'HomeScreen' object has no attribute '_trigger_layout'"

Tags: python, kivy, boxlayout

Why does this code generate the following error?

> AttributeError: 'HomeScreen' object has no attribute '_trigger_layout'

```
class HomeScreen(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self):

        print "homescreen"

        topbar = BoxLayout(spacing = -2, size = (64, 64), size_hint = (1, None))

        back_button = Button(size = (32, 64), size_hint = (None, 1), text = '>', font_size = 15 + 0.015 * self.height, background_color = (0.239, 0.815, 0.552, 1))
        home_button = Button(text = "HOME", font_size = 10 + 0.015 * self.width, background_color = (0.239, 0.815, 0.552, 1))
        more_button = Button(size = (32, 64), size_hint = (None, 1), text = '...', font_size = 15 + 0.015 * self.height, background_color = (0.239, 0.815, 0.552, 1))

        topbar.add_widget(back_button)
        topbar.add_widget(home_button)
        topbar.add_widget(more_button)

        self.add_widget(topbar)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have overwritten the init method, which is needed. In the code below I am also overwriting the init method, but I am also calling the init method before it was overwritten.

```
class HomeScreen(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(HomeScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        ...
```

---

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.slider import Slider
from kivy.uix.treeview import TreeView, TreeViewNode
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.slider import Slider
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

class HomeScreen(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(HomeScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)


        print("homescreen")

        topbar = BoxLayout(spacing = 0, size = (64, 64), size_hint = (1, None))

        back_button = Button(size = (32, 64), size_hint = (None, 1), text = '>', font_size = 15 + 0.015 * self.height, background_color = (0.239, 0.815, 0.552, 1))
        home_button = Button(text = "HOME", font_size = 10 + 0.015 * self.width, background_color = (0.239, 0.815, 0.552, 1))
        more_button = Button(size = (32, 64), size_hint = (None, 1), text = '...', font_size = 15 + 0.015 * self.height, background_color = (0.239, 0.815, 0.552, 1))

        topbar.add_widget(back_button)
        topbar.add_widget(home_button)
        topbar.add_widget(more_button)
        self.add_widget(topbar)


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return HomeScreen()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

[image]

Comment: now my buttons are not visible, i've a blank screen, do you know how to fix this?

Comment: If I copy and paste my code I get what I have above (see added Screenshot). Don't you get that too?

Comment: When I isolate your code in a debug file, it works. But when I integrate it with my application already advanced, it does not display the 3 buttons.

Comment: are using a kv file or in py code? If you post more code, I can try to integrate it there

Comment: Both. Can I send you my full code by private message to get your help ?

Comment: I will not post an email adress. Best is to create a github gist or pastebin or sth like that.

Comment: Did my answer solve or help your question? Please consider accepting or upvoting.

Comment: Oh sorry. I forgot to answer you after testing new code. You helped me to fix my problem. Thank you.